# Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, citrix

Was anybody able to install Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 12.10?

Both 32 bit and 64 bit deb package fail to install properly.

here is the error message for installing 64 bit package:

```bash
sudo dpkg -i icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 139512 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace icaclient 12.1.0 (using icaclient_12.1.0_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement icaclient ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
 icaclient depends on nspluginwrapper; however:
  Package nspluginwrapper is not installed.
dpkg: error processing icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

It seems like the problem is that it needs `nspluginwrapper` and `nspluginwrapper` needs `nspluginviewer` and `nspluginviewer` is not available in Ubuntu 12.10

When I try to install the 32 bit deb package I get the following error message:

```bash
sudo dpkg -i icaclient-12.1.0_i386.deb 
dpkg: error processing icaclient-12.1.0_i386.deb (--install):
 package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient-12.1.0_i386.deb
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Citrix receiver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40723/how-do-i-install-citrix-receiver)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10. It seems that you have to install nspluginwrapper first. This can be done with the software center for example. After that the install worked fine.

Comment: Hi Rob, are you using 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu? I am not able to install  nspluginwrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The error popping is just about a postinst script failing to detect x64 arch. You can edit the postinstall file and run `apt-get install -f` to clean error messages.

See this article:
[CitrixICAClientHowTo - Community Ubuntu Documentation: Citrix ICA Client 12 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CitrixICAClientHowTo#Citrix_ICA_Client_12_on_Ubuntu_12.04_64-bit)

Particulary this excerpt:

> Beware - this should be used with caution as it will install with an error. The postinst script exits 2 as it fails to correctly determine the architecture of the system. The ICAClient package will function, but APT will complain that ICAClient is "not fully installed or removed" and you will get errors each time you use a package manager.
>
> This can be fixed by unpacking the deb and editing the regular expression in line 2648 of the postinst script to match x86_64. Then rebuild the deb and it should install without a problem.
>
> Alternatively `/var/lib/dpkg/info/icaclient.postinst` can be edited after an installation that gives an error and `apt-get -f install` can be run afterwards.

Comment: the error is not related to postinscript. The error is related to failed dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

icaclient will throw errors that it failed to install when it installed correctly. I installed it just fine using the Ubuntu Software Center, it worked although it still said install failed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use a patched installation package, check out this:
[dpkg reports error on package icaclient](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147156/dpkg-reports-error-on-package-icaclient)

I opened a [forum thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074811) to get more hints and tips to get it work:

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on 12.10 (32 bit).  It's mostly from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645173&page=3

1. `sudo apt-get install nspluginwrapper`
2. Click to download from http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/receivers-by-platform/receiver-for-linux-121.html and then install automatically using Ubuntu Software Center
3. Create new file `/usr/share/applications/wfica.desktop`

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Citrix ICA client
   GenericName=Citrix ICA Client
   Comment=Citrix nFuse session file
   Categories=Application
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Exec=/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica
   Icon=wfica
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   MimeType=application/x-ica
   ```
4. Create new file `/usr/share/mime/packages/ica.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
   <mime-type type="application/x-ica">
   <comment>Citrix ICA launcher</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.ica"/>
   </mime-type>
   </mime-info>
   ```
5. `sudo update-desktop-database && sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`
6. `sudo gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list`and add the line: `application/x-ica=wfica.desktop`
7. Run the following from the command line:

   ```
   sudo xdg-mime install --novendor /usr/share/mime/packages/ica.xml
   sudo xdg-mime default wfica.desktop application/x-ica
   ```

For me, this now allows citrix to work from both Chromium and Firefox on Ubuntu 12.10.